# This in an object is returning [object Window], not the parent object

Tags: javascript, object, reference, window, this

I want to make an event handler with setters and getters, but there is a problem. The this keyword is not working in my function inside the object correctly. I was looking everywhere, but I couldn't find the problem.

```
const Event = {
    listen: ()=>{
        console.log(this);
    }
};
Event.listen();
```

This is a part of my code which returns me: `Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}`.

I tryed searching on google, documentation (mozzila), stackoverflow. I tryed deleting all parts of code to have only this object with this funciton.

I am excepting, that the `this` will return the `Event{listen:function}` object.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm just wondering what have you actually searched for, this is not too hard to find from [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#cannot_be_used_as_methods) either.